# Perl: After merging text files into 1 file won't read the whole file

Tags: perl, file

The code below puts text files given from the command line and puts them in a merged.txt file. This part makes a perfect copy with the correct amount of lines. My problem is that when trying to use the file for example with while(file) it doesn't go through every line. For example merged.txt will have 735 lines as counted by vim but numlines will only have 732.

```
my @file = map { open my $f, $_ or die "Can't Open $_:$!"; $f } @ARGV;
open my $out_file, ">merged.txt" or die "Can't Open out_file $!";
my $output;
do {
    $output ='';
    foreach(@file) {
        my $line = <$_>;
        if(defined $line) {
            if($line !~/\n$/) {
                $line .= "\n";
            }
            $output .= $line;
         }
    }
    print {$out_file} $output;
}
while ($output ne '');
my $numlines =0;
open my $file, '<', 'merged.txt' or die "Could not open file 'merged.txt' $0";
while(<$file>) {
    $numlines++;
}
```

Comment: Try closing the output file to flush it before reopening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the answer, to close the file you wrote before opening it for reading.<sup>†</sup> Another way to have that happen is to use the same filehandle, which does get closed as it's being opened again. So

```
my $file = 'merged.txt';
open my $out_file, '>', $file or die ...
...
open $out_file, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
```

if you *are* done writing by then. 
Note that you want the [variable $!](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) (not `$0`, the name of the script).

I'd like to also mention that if your filenames are in `@ARGV` you can use the [special `<>`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)

```
my $output;    
$output .= $_ while <>;
```

or, if you don't need all merged content in a variable

```
open my $fh_out, '>', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
print $fh_out $_ while <>;
close $fh_out;
```

The `<>` is a synonym for the magical `<ARGV>`. It reads all lines from all files in `@ARGV`, but please see more in the linked documentation.

---

<sup>†</sup>   Working with a file which is opened elsewhere can badly confuse things unless one is very careful. One way to keep it straight is by using [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)

> Due to the rules and rigors of ANSI C, on some systems you have to do a `seek` whenever you switch between reading and writing.

so

```
open my $out_file, '>', $file or die ...
...
seek $out_file, 0, 0;
```

and after this the reads should work correctly (you should get the correct line count).

While this is a little more efficient it is error prone and tricky. Unless there is a demonstrated need for `seek`-ing around a file I'd recommend just to re-open the file for reading after writing is done.

Comment: @drake I added a comment on reading from a file that's being written to (still open).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are opening `merged.txt` for writing

```
open my $out_file, ">merged.txt" or die "Can't Open out_file $!";
```

then you want to open it again for reading

```
open my $file, '<', 'merged.txt' or die "Could not open file 'merged.txt' $0";
```

Yet you never close the file, so close the file at this point

```
    ...
}
close $out_file or die "Unable to close $file: $!"; # here we close it!
while ($output ne '');
my $numlines =0;
open my $file, '<', 'merged.txt' or die "Could not open file 'merged.txt' $!";
```

Then do the same close after you read from file.

All that being said, what is the reason you writing to file and then reading from it again when you are already storing all values locally? or is it just another post check? It is a little bit of an overkill, but nothing serious.

Lastly, this is a better method to open a file, see [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

```
open(my $fh, "<", "merged.txt") or die "Unable to open < merged.txt: $!";
```

Comment: The reason for the files was mostly me messing around with files. The close file was the issue, but why was that? What was while(file) reading that it didn't want to count a line?

Comment: @drake If your file is still open for writing, it will be written to, but it does not completely cache the content in file until you close it, alsmost like saving it.. It is sort of the same as you editing a file in notepad and saving it occasionally, but if you do not do the final save, it will not save the final content.